# How do I display fields in sql vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I have this query

```
 select 
raw_item_no, 
raw_item_no_2,
raw_item_no_3,
raw_item_no_4 
from jtjobfil_sql 
where job_no = 213418
```

which outputs like this

```
raw_item_no    raw_item_no_2  raw_item_no_3  raw_item_no_4
 23              24              25               26
```

how do I get the output to look like this

```
raw_item_nos
23
24
25
26
```

I looked into pivot but I couldn't figure out how to do this because I am not summing any columns.

Comment: Instead of `PIVOT` you need `UNPIVOT` - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT x.raw_item_nos
FROM jtjobfil_sql  t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (t.raw_item_no),
        (t.raw_item_no_2),
        (t.raw_item_no_3),
        (t.raw_item_no_4)
) X (raw_item_nos)
WHERE job_no = 213418;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something using a union.

```
with my_query (column1, column2, column3)
as 
(
    SELECT column1, column2, column3
    FROM my_table
    where id = 1
)
SELECT column1 FROM my_query
UNION
SELECT column2 FROM my_query
UNION
SELECT column3 FROM my_query
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case all you need `UNPIVOT` and list of columns.

Query is very simple

```
 SELECT P AS raw_item_no
    FROM (
           SELECT raw_item_no
               ,raw_item_no_2
               ,raw_item_no_3
               ,raw_item_no_4
            FROM jtjobfil_sql
            WHERE job_no = 213418
         ) p UNPIVOT ( p FOR value IN ( raw_item_no, raw_item_no_2, raw_item_no_3, raw_item_no_4 ) ) AS unvpt
```

here is sample data and example of `UNPIVOT`

```
 DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
     raw_item_no INT
    ,raw_item_no_2 INT
    ,raw_item_no_3 INT
    ,raw_item_no_4 INT
    )

 INSERT INTO @table
    VALUES ( 23, 24, 25, 26 )

 SELECT P AS raw_item_no
    FROM (
           SELECT raw_item_no
               ,raw_item_no_2
               ,raw_item_no_3
               ,raw_item_no_4
            FROM @table
     ) p UNPIVOT ( p FOR value IN ( raw_item_no, raw_item_no_2, raw_item_no_3, raw_item_no_4 ) ) AS unvpt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick also to solve the particular name only

this is also one type of logic to handle this type of Question but this is very more lengthy code

```
SELECT  substr(ename,1,1) FROM  employees WHERE ENAME='JAMES'
UNION ALL
select  substr(ename,2,1) from employees WHERE ENAME= 'JAMES'
UNION ALL
select  substr(ename,3,1) from employees WHERE ENAME= 'JAMES'
UNION ALL
select  substr(ename,4,1) from employees WHERE ENAME= 'JAMES'
UNION ALL 
select  substr(ename,5,1) from employees WHERE ENAME= 'JAMES'
```