# How to take sql query results and turn vertical and output in specific format

Tags: sql

I am really new to SQL. I have this query

```
SELECT
     1
    ,2
    ,20
    ,50
    ,100
    ,200
    ,201
    ,202
    ,203
    ,204
    ,205
    ,206
    ,210
    ,215
    ,220
    ,221
    ,225
    ,230
    ,235
    ,240
    ,245
    ,250
    ,255
    ,261
    ,262
    ,263
    ,368
    ,369
FROM Data_Table 
ORDER BY CAST(3 AS DATE), 6,  1 DESC
```

That outputs the data like this

```
1      2            20           50    100       200   201   202   203  204  205  206  210   215 ....369
1000A  Test Desc 1  02-01-1993   Yes   Testing   AAA                                   1.00 
1000A  Test Desc 2  04-01-1995   Yes   Testing   BBB                         BB        2.00
1000A  Test Desc 3  09-01-1999   Yes   Testing   CCC                                   3.00
                    09-01-1999                   DDD                         DD        4.00
                    09-01-1999                   EEE                                   5.00
                    09-01-1999                   FFF                                   6.00
                    09-01-1999                   GGG                                   7.00
                    09-01-1999                   HHH                         HH        8.00
1000A  Test Desc 4  02-01-2006   Yes   Testing   III                                   9.00
1000A  Test Desc 5  09-01-2007   Yes   Testing   JJJ                                   10.00
1000A  Test Desc 6  01-01-2008   Yes   Testing   KKK                         KK        11.00
                    01-01-2008                   LLL                                   12.00
                    01-01-2008                   MMM                                   13.00
                    01-01-2008                   NNN                                   14.00
```

I need to have it output the data vertically in the format below. When columns 1, 2, 50 & 100 have data in them, then it needs to include it in the output file as shown, but when there is no data in columns 1, 2, 50 & 100 then dont output those rows.

```
##Header1
##Header2
1,1000A
2,Test Desc 1
20,02-01-1993
50,Yes
100,Testing
200,AAA
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,1
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
1,1000A
2,Test Desc 2
20,04-01-1995
50,Yes
100,Testing
200,BBB
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,BB
206,
210,2
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
1,1000A
2,Test Desc 3
20,09-01-1999
50,Yes
100,Testing
200,CCC
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,3
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,09-01-1999
200,DDD
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,DD
206,
210,4
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,09-01-1999
200,EEE
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,5
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,09-01-1999
200,FFF
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,6
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,09-01-1999
200,GGG
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,7
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,09-01-1999
200,HHH
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,HH
206,
210,8
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
1,1000A
2,Test Desc 4
20,02-01-2006
50,Yes
100,Testing
200,III
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,9
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
1,1000A
2,Test Desc 5
20,09-01-2007
50,Yes
100,Testing
200,JJJ
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,10
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
1,1000A
2,Test Desc 6
20,01-01-2008
50,Yes
100,Testing
200,KKK
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,KK
206,
210,11
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,01-01-2008
200,LLL
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,12
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,01-01-2008
200,MMM
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,13
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
20,01-01-2008
200,NNN
201,
202,
203,
204,
205,
206,
210,14
215,
220,
221,
225,
230,
235,
240,
245,
250,
255,
261,
262,
263,
368,
369,
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps use `CROSS APPLY` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845768/how-do-i-display-fields-in-sql-vertically-instead-of-horizontally